# Instantiating one instance each of parent's class children?

Tags: php, class, inheritance

For testing my stuff i would like to automaticaly instantiate one instance each per child of a parent class i name, without calling the class name manually (its too many).

For example:

```
Class Animal {
  public weight;
}

Class Dog extends Animal {
  public weight = 20;
}

Class SmallDog extends Dog {
  public weight = 18;
}

Class Cat extends Animal {
  public weight = 10;
}


function xy(){
  $classes = array();
  foreach parent->child as child(){
    $classes[] = new child()
  }
  //$classes = [Dog, SmallDog, Cat]
}
```

Is something like (tm) doable and if so, how ?

As further information, i have an autoload_register that holds each class, but it also holds various classes i dont want to instantiate.
Also, relative to the above example, i have Animal, Dog and Cat all assembled in a single file, lets call it animal.php.

In the code above, i would except to get an instance of anything below Animal, including SmallDog. If its not possible that way, i would be okay with getting Dog and Cat and calling the function with parent being Dog (to get SmallDog instantiated).

thanks for your advice,

Comment: You can use [`get_declared_classes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php) and [`ReflectionClass::getParentClass()`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getparentclass.php) to find the classes that extends some class (assuming all the files that contain the children classes are loaded) but this will make your code harder to read and understand. It's much clearer to just list the child classes. You can use some simple shell scripting (`grep`, `sed`/`cut` etc) to extract the list of children classes from the code.

Comment: This defies the idea of testing.. You do inheritance and override functions as each subclass has different behavior than its parent.. and you must test them.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really useful in real case scenarios but using @axiac comment you can implement `ChildrenResolver` class:

```
class ChildrenResolver
{ 
    protected $defaultClasses = [
        0 => 'stdClass',
        1 => 'Exception',
        2 => 'ErrorException',
        // ...
    ];

    protected $declaredClasses;

    public function __construct(array $declaredClasses = null)
    {
        if (is_null($declaredClasses)) {
            $declaredClasses = array_diff(
                get_declared_classes(),
                $this->defaultClasses
            );
        }

        $this->declaredClasses = $declaredClasses;
    }

    public function getChildClasses($class)
    {
        return array_filter(
            $this->declaredClasses,
            function ($declaredClassName) use ($class) {
                $declaredClass = new ReflectionClass($declaredClassName);

                while(($parent = $declaredClass->getParentClass())) {
                    if ($parent->name === $class) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    $declaredClass = $parent;
                }

                return false;
            }
        );
    }

    public function getDirectChildClasses($class)
    {
        return array_filter(
            $this->declaredClasses,
            function ($declaredClassName) use ($class) {
                $declaredClass = new ReflectionClass($declaredClassName);

                $parent = $declaredClass->getParentClass();

                return $parent ? $parent->name === $class : false;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The idea is pretty simple. We loop over declared classes (obtained via [`get_declared_classes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php)), reflect every class using [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) and compare parent, which we get from [`ReflectionClass::getParentClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getparentclass.php), with given parent. For the sake of convinience I used [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function.

Having this class you can resolve children like this:

```
$childrenResolver = new ChildrenResolver;

var_dump($childrenResolver->getChildClasses('Animal'));
var_dump($childrenResolver->getDirectChildClasses('Animal'));
var_dump($childrenResolver->getChildClasses('Dog'));
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e2b868ef327dbe63965eb994177135315beb3a92).